# how to logic if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

**Update 2:**
I need your help into the efficient logic to solve the following problem
The user will get some question .Every time he answer the correctly his position cell will move (Now he is in raw==3, col==0;) depend in how many attempts :

- First Guess  : +2points + move(up,right)
- Second Guess  : +1point +move(right)
- Third Guess  : -2points + move(down,left)

See the picture:http://postimg.org/image/va5146on7/

My problem when for example if the user guess from First attempt But his current position **in the raw=0,colum=x**Then he have only the choice to move up …..and so on for the rest...

I tried it but it doesn’t get right for every possibility .Any help?

```
private void Moveposition() {
    if (count == 1) {
        if (raw == 0 && colu <= 7) {colu++;}   //if reach the up border      
        if (colu == 7 && raw <= 7 && raw != 0) {raw--;}//if rech  left border
        if (!(raw == 0 && colu <= 7) && !(colu == 7 && raw <= 7 && raw != 0)) {
            raw--;
            colu++;
        }

        System.out.print("r" + raw + "c" + colu);

        // JButton button1 = this.GamelButtons[raw][col];
        JourneyScore += 2;
        this.ScoreLabel.setText("" + JourneyScore);
    }

    if (count == 2) {
        if (colu == 7 && raw <= 7) {raw--;}//if rech  left border
        else {colu++;}

        JourneyScore += 1;
        this.ScoreLabel.setText("" + JourneyScore);
    }

    if (count == 3) {
        if (colu == 0 && raw <= 7) {raw++;}   //if reach the left border go down
        if (colu == 0 && raw == 7) {raw--;}//if it the start position do not do any thing 
        if (raw == 7 && colu <= 7 && colu != 0) {colu--;}//if rech  down border go left
        if (!(colu == 0 && raw <= 7) && !(raw == 7 && colu <= 7 && colu != 0) && !(colu == 0 && raw == 7)) {
            raw++;
            colu--;
        }

        JourneyScore -= 1;
        this.ScoreLabel.setText("" + JourneyScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  The picture didn't help much.

Comment: goodness, postimg has a lot of pr0n at the head and foot of a given page.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a whole lot about what you are trying to accomplish, I would discourage you from checking valid actions (eg `if (raw==0&&colu<=7){colu++;}`) here.  Setters or helper methods are much better suited to that.

Determine the user's 'point' reward, then instruct another method to move the columns and rows, placing the logic required to validate the moves there.

Comment: mmm I already getting the colu & raw as global variable ,some possibility are working but not all, see I update my code.First Guess it seems work fine BUT Second Guess and third not all.